# Use data in view from controller from ng-click angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Pretty new to angular and having a little trouble getting data from controller and displaying in view using ionic.

I have a function in a controller ('DashCtrl') where I pass through a string to use within the function by using ng-click. For now I just want to take this string and display it in the next view as I have an href on the same element I have the ng-click event.

When I log the string on the next page, it is working and shows up. How do I get to use this in the view?

Heres the code:

HTML

*first page

```
<ul contentful-entries>
  <div ng-repeat="story in $contentfulEntries.items">
    <li class="story col col-100">
      <a href="#/tab/story/{{story.fields.slug}}" ng-click='storyDetails("{{story.fields.title}}")'>
        <p>{{ story.fields.title }}</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

*redirects to this on the ng-click

```
<ion-view view-title="Story">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item" ng-click="goBack()">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"> Back</i> 
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list ng-controller="DashCtrl">
      <h1>{{ story.slug }} </h1>
      <p> <!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE STRING --> </p>   
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

*heres my controller

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicHistory) {

  $scope.storyDetails = function($scope, details) {
    // here is the data i need to display in the view
    // the console.log shows up in the browser
    console.log(details);
  }

  $scope.goBack = function(){
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  }

  // this is working fine
  $scope.story = $stateParams;
})
```

Comment: I probably have done this wrong and people have said not to use it, but I got this working using the `rootScope` to save the variable and take it to the next view. I found out that the log was actually taking place on the first view and not the second view I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the $rootScope. I know this may not be the best solution but I am just trying to grasp Angular at the moment.

In my controller I used

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $rootScope, $ionicHistory) {

  $scope.goBack = function(){
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  }

  $scope.storyDetails = function(details) {
    $rootScope.details = details;
    return $rootScope.details;
  }
})
```

Then I am able to use the $rootScope.details in another controller to use in a function I need the string for.

I know I'm not doing this the Angular way, so if anyone would be kind enough to show me how to do this 'properly' without using the rootScope, I'd be forever in your debt.

Answer (score 0):

Save the details string as a controller variable, and then you can access this within the view.

Comment: I am saving the string as a controller variable, but getting undefined when i try and bind it to the view. any thoughts on what to do next?

Comment: in the code you have posted, you are not saving it as a controller variable

Comment: I mean I went in and saved it as a controller variable but I was still getting an undefined empty variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assign variable `details` to some other variable like`$scope.newVar = details` and then in ur view you can display that by just binding it in this way `{{newVar}}`.

Hope you got it.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I get an undefined variable even though I have assigned it to another variable. When I log the variable it shows as undefined and doesn't display when I bind it to the view.